# Unable to connect to Cloud Foundry Redis cups when Upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am upgrading an existing Spring Boot Project from 2.6.14 to 3.1.1.  After my upgrade I am no longer able to connect to Redis using my cups in Tanzu Cloud Foundry.  The cups is working for both Postgres and RMQ, but for some reason Redis is having an issue.

I put the external Redis connection details in application.properties and it works fine.  When I remove this, however, it tries to connect to the local host default and is ignoring my Redis cups.

I tried adding @ImportAutoConfiguration and that did not help.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAsync
@EnableRetry
@EnableCaching
@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class,RedisAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
```

This is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>pcf-upgrade-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>pcf-upgrade-api</name>
    <description>My 3.1 project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <skip.it>true</skip.it>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/config/**/*, **/exceptions/**/*, **/dto/**/*, **/feign/client/**/*,
            **/Application.java</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emc.it.cpe</groupId>
            <artifactId>cpe-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14</version>
        </dependency>
                
        
        <!-- Swagger version 3.0.0 currently does not work with spring 2.6 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
             <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
             <version>r05</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.cfenv</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-cfenv-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>    

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas or has faced a similar issue.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

redis configuration properties are now prefixed with `spring.data.redis`, they were previously prefixed `spring.redis`